# Configure custom roles for SelfMutation, Assets in CDK pipeline instead of auto generate one for each pipeline

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-cdk-custom-resource

I have a CDK pipeline (aws-cdk-lib : 2.99.1) and I will be creating lot of CDK pipelines (25+ repositories, each will have their own pipeline ). I have created some custom roles (CodeBuildRole, CodePipelineRole, CodeDeployRole, CodePipelineEventsRole ) to set permission s for each pipeline at once.

I have configured some of the custom roles.

- CodeBuildStep -> CodeBuildStepProps -> actionRole
- CodeBuildStep -> CodeBuildStepProps -> role
- CodeBuildStep -> CodeBuildStepProps -> input -> CodePipelineSource -> CodeCommitSourceOptions -> eventRole
- CodePipeline -> CodePipelineProps -> role

But when I deploy the pipeline, cdk will create another 4 roles. Is there a way to stop generating those roles and tell CDK to reuse existing ones ?

- AWS:${cdk-codepipeline-XX/UpdatePipeline/SelfMutation/Role}
- AWS:${cdk-codepipeline-XX/Assets/FileRole}
- AWS:${cdk-codepipeline-XX/Pipeline/Source/source-change/CodePipelineActionRole}
- AWS:${cdk-codepipeline-XX/CodeBuildActionRole}

  ```
   String codePipeline = "cdk-codepipeline-" + repoName;
   CodePipeline pipeline = new CodePipeline(
           this,
           codePipeline,
           CodePipelineProps.builder()
                   .pipelineName(codePipeline)
                   .selfMutation(Boolean.TRUE)
                   .role(codePipelineRole)
                   .synth(synthStep)
                   .crossAccountKeys(Boolean.TRUE)
                   .artifactBucket(getArtifactBucket())
                   .synthCodeBuildDefaults(
                           CodeBuildOptions
                                   .builder()
                                   .cache(codebuildCache)
                                   .rolePolicy(List.of(policyStatement))
                                   .buildEnvironment(buildEnvironment)
                                   .build()
                   )
                   .codeBuildDefaults(
                           CodeBuildOptions
                                   .builder()
                                   .cache(codebuildCache)
                                   .rolePolicy(List.of(policyStatement))
                                   .buildEnvironment(buildEnvironment)
                                   .build()
                   )
                   .selfMutationCodeBuildDefaults(
                           CodeBuildOptions
                                   .builder()
                                   .cache(codebuildCache)
                                   .rolePolicy(List.of(policyStatement))
                                   .buildEnvironment(buildEnvironment)
                                   .build()
                   )
                   .assetPublishingCodeBuildDefaults(
                           CodeBuildOptions
                                   .builder()
                                   .cache(codebuildCache)
                                   .rolePolicy(List.of(policyStatement))
                                   .buildEnvironment(buildEnvironment)
                                   .build()
                   )
                   .build()
   );

   String functionName = "dev-" + repoName;

   pipeline.addStage(
           new LambdaPipelineStage(
                   this,
                   repoName + "-dev-deploy",
                   StageProps
                           .builder()
                           .stageName(repoName + "-dev-deploy")
                           .build(),
                   functionName,
                   Constants.DEVELOPMENT_ENV

           )
   );
   String codeBuildName = "cdk-" + repoName + "-codebuild";
   CodeBuildStep synthStep = new CodeBuildStep(
           codeBuildName,
           CodeBuildStepProps
                   .builder()
                   .projectName(codeBuildName)
                   .cache(codebuildCache)
                   .input(
                           CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(
                                   codeCommitRepository,
                                   "master",
                                   CodeCommitSourceOptions
                                           .builder()
                                           .eventRole(codePipelineEventRole)
                                           .actionName("source-change")
                                           .build()
                           )
                   )
                   .partialBuildSpec(getPartialBuildSpec())
                   .installCommands(getInstallCommands())
                   .commands(getBuildCommands())
                   .primaryOutputDirectory("${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/cdk/cdk.out")
                   .buildEnvironment(buildEnvironment)
                   .actionRole(codePipelineRole)
                   .role(codeBuildRole)
                   .rolePolicyStatements(List.of(policyStatement))
                   .build()
   );
  ```